# Open AJAX link in new window or tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, preventdefault

I have a page with links that load new content into one of the divs. This work fine, but I would also like to give the user the option to open those links in a new tab if they right-click and choose to 'open in new tab'.

So, the javascript AJAX would handle the loading of the new content normally, but then if they select 'open in new tab' perhaps the main `HREF` would fire and bring the user to the full page with content in the other tab. Something like:

```
<a href="example.com/fullPageWithContent.html" onclick="loadContentOnly(1);">Click me</a>

<script>
function loadContentOnly(n) {
event.preventDefault(); //Some condition here?

// AJAX load content for n...

};
</script>
```

How is this best achieved? (I'm using jQuery, but a vanilla solution even better!)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the marked question above. Anyone reading both can quickly determine that. How do I remove the duplicate notice?

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear if determination to show in new page is global or not.

Following assumes it is predetermined

```
<a href="example.com/fullPageWithContent.html" onclick="return loadContent(1, this);">Click me</a>

<script>
function loadContent(n, el) {

  if(showInNewPage){
     el.target = '_blank';
     return true;
  } else{    
      // AJAX load content for n...

      return false;    
};
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'is global'? I edited the question to clarify it. The problem is how to implement the HREF fallback if someone selects 'open tab in new window'.

Comment: Would be the variable based on you mentioning that you plan to give users an option. If this isn't what you expected need a more detailed explanation of how you wnted it to work